# how to format widgets so they are on opposite ends but also within the alignment of the other widgets

Tags: flutter

I have been trying to find a way to keep two text widgets apart but the problem was that if I used Spacer() or mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween the text goes outside the alignment of the other widgets
[desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CEZr.png) vs [current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1sef.png)

```
child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Container(
          child: Column(children: [
            Text(
              'Notes Made',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Accordion(
              color: 0xffE69AF2,
              title: receiptData.getVisitType(),
              content: receiptData.getVisitDesc(),
            ),
            Accordion(
              color: 0xff9AF2AE,
              title: 'Doctor\'s Notes',
              content: receiptData.getDoctorNotes(),
            ),
            Text(
              'Receipt',
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    'consultation fee:',
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    receiptData.getCFees().toString(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            RatingBar.builder(
              initialRating: receiptData.getRating(),
              ignoreGestures: true,
              minRating: 1,
              direction: Axis.horizontal,
              allowHalfRating: true,
              itemCount: 5,
              itemPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, _) => Icon(
                Icons.star,
                color: Colors.amber,
              ),
              onRatingUpdate: (rating) {
                print(receiptData.getRating());
              },
            ),
          ]),
        ),
```

Comment: please provide  a minimal reproduce code.

Comment: could you include your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping each text widget in a container and setting the width of each container to a specific value.

```dart
Container(
  width: 50.0,  // container width 
  child: Text(
    'Text 1',
  ),
),
Container(
  width: 50.0, 
  child: Text(
    'Text 2',
  ),
),
```

Additionally you could try wrapping both text widgets in a Row widget and set the `mainAxisSize` property to `MainAxisSize.min`. This will force the row to shrink-wrap the text widgets, allowing you to control the space between them by setting the `mainAxisAlignment` property to `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Text('Text 1'),
    Text('Text 2'),
  ],
),
```

Comment: the first one just makes it go down a line while the second one squishes the words together rather than spacing them far apart